# Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 Issues

Tags: cmd.exe, hyper-v

I have Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 and it won't boot past cmd. I have tried going to recovery mode, and safe mode, and I got there, however it keeps booting me back to the same place. At this point I don't care if all my files are deleted as long as I can get Windows back, and get my desktop back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mircrosoft Hyper-V Server 2012 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833684(v=ws.11).aspx) is a virtualisation platform not a full operating system. It does not contain GUI:

> Hyper-V Server does not contain a graphical user interface. Instead, you configure Hyper-V Server by using the Server Configuration tool (Sconfig.cmd). <sup>[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj647783(v=ws.11).aspx)</sup>

So what you see is a correct situation. If you installed Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 over an existing system, your files are probably gone (you might try to retrieve them, but it requires effort and tools).

If you want a desktop environment, you need to install an operating system like Windows 10 or Windows Server.